# Applying a custom sort to Google Sheets string column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, regex, sorting, regexextract

I am trying to sort a table of rows by their first column that is comprised of strings with this format (capital letters followed by a dash followed by numbers).

Using the default string sort I get something like this:

```
BB-1
BB-11
BB-12
BB-2
BB-3
BL-1
BL-14
BL-15
MAN-4
MAN-45
MAN-5
```

How can I sort it first by the char prefix followed by the integer suffix so my result is as follows:

```
BB-1
BB-2
BB-3
BB-11
BB-12
BL-1
BL-14
BL-15
MAN-4
MAN-5
MAN-45
```

I've attempted to do this using a formula with some regular expressions, but it doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
=sort(A2:A,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"^\w+"),true, REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+$"), true)
```

Answer (score 1):

This formula did the trick:

`=sort(A2:A,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"^\w+"),true, VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+$")), true)`

My first attempt was missing the string to value conversion.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you.